# How to split NAME into 3 different fields FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME & LAST_NAME when there is a space

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to split NAME into 3 different fields `FIRST_NAME,  MIDDLE_NAME & LAST_NAME`.

Currently the NAME filed is in the following format
    `[FIRST_NAME || ' ' || MIDDLE_NAME|| ' ' ||LAST_NAME]`. To be more clear suppose a person name is

```
FIRST_NAME: SHERRY 
MIDDLE_NAME: L
LAST_NAME : CLEAVES
```

then  the NAME field has "SHERRY L CLEAVES", I want it in 3 different fields. Also, How do I handle if there are only two names?

some of the sample data as follows:

```
  ('William  Sears',
       'PETER E LABBE',
       'Edith  Roberts',
       'SHERRY L CLEAVES',
       'Sharon  Matthes',
       'TAMMY L PELLETIER',
       'STACIE M KINER',
       'MICHAEL C THOMAS',
       'CHESTER R DAVIS',
       'MICHAEL D HUTCHINSON',
       'Paul  Mikkelsen'
       )
```

Comment: You can use `instr` function to find the position of spaces and `substr` function to break up a string.

Comment: Is this a real problem or is this a homework assignment?  In reality, names are messy.  "Oscar de la Hoya" is a first name and a last name with multiple spaces and no middle name.  If you have to handle real world data, the problem is vastly more complicated unless you're fine with making a fair number of mistakes.

Comment: @JustinCave - in this case I would rather guess a real-life problem, judging by the poster's screen name. I can't see a student coming up with that name. It's probably just someone who develops with PeopleTools and perhaps Java, and doesn't do a lot of Oracle SQL work day to day. Happens even in the largest organizations.

Comment: @mathguy - That would be my guess as well (though it could be someone taking an Oracle SQL class).  If it's a real world problem, though, my answer would generally be "don't try to do it yourself" because real world data is messy and people tend to get very worked up over incorrect names.  If you're right 99% of the time, 99 people won't care and the 100th will be really upset that you butchered his or her name.

Comment: @JustinCave - I can see this as a one-time, data cleanup job - telling people "we did our best but please check, especially if you have an unusual name, and let us know what we got wrong." That's what I would do if it was my (work) assignment. :-)

Comment: @mathguy - If these are employee names, I could imagine saying that (though I'd wager that there was another source with the names parsed out).  I'd be hard-pressed to imagine sending all my customers a "Dear Mr. Hoya, Please check your name for us.  If we got it wrong, please fill out this form to correct it.  Thanks" email.

Comment: @JustinCave - Right. psoft is for HR though (mostly) - it didn't cross my mind these would be anything other than employees.

Comment: @mathguy - There are a whole range of PeopleSoft applications.  CRM is one of the more popular ones.  HR is another biggie.  But if we're talking HR, I'll wager that you could get the properly separated names from somewhere else rather than writing this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
with data_qry
as
(
select 'William  Sears' as name from dual union all
select 'PETER E LABBE' as name from dual union all
select 'Edith  Roberts' as name from dual union all
select 'SHERRY L CLEAVES' as name from dual union all
select 'Sharon  Matthes' as name from dual union all
select 'TAMMY L PELLETIER' as name from dual union all
select 'STACIE M KINER' as name from dual union all
select 'MICHAEL C THOMAS' as name from dual union all
select 'CHESTER R DAVIS' as name from dual union all
select 'MICHAEL D HUTCHINSON' as name from dual union all
select 'Paul  Mikkelsen' as name from dual
)
select name
     , substr(name, 1, instr(name, ' ', 1)) as first
     , case when instr(name, ' ', 1, 2) > 0 then substr(name, instr(name, ' ', 1, 1) + 1, instr(name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(name, ' ', 1, 1) - 1) else null end as middle
     , case when instr(name, ' ', 1, 2) > 0 then substr(name, instr(name, ' ', 1, 2) + 1) else substr(name, instr(name, ' ', 1, 1) + 1) end as last
from data_qry
```

Output:

```
NAME                 FIRST      MIDDLE     LAST
William  Sears       William               Sears
PETER E LABBE        PETER      E          LABBE
Edith  Roberts       Edith                 Roberts
SHERRY L CLEAVES     SHERRY     L          CLEAVES
Sharon  Matthes      Sharon                Matthes
TAMMY L PELLETIER    TAMMY      L          PELLETIER
STACIE M KINER       STACIE     M          KINER
MICHAEL C THOMAS     MICHAEL    C          THOMAS
CHESTER R DAVIS      CHESTER    R          DAVIS
MICHAEL D HUTCHINSON MICHAEL    D          HUTCHINSON
Paul  Mikkelsen      Paul                  Mikkelsen
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. I took care of a few possibilities, like an arbitrary number of spaces between first and last name (no middle initial) or between first name and initial, or between initial and last name. Also multi-letter initials. There will still be plenty of other, unanticipated problems, like people with two first names or two last names, etc.

```
with input_strings ( str ) as (
       select 'William  Sears'       from dual union all
       select 'PETER E LABBE'        from dual union all
       select 'Edith  Roberts'       from dual union all
       select 'SHERRY L CLEAVES'     from dual union all
       select 'Sharon  Matthes'      from dual union all
       select 'TAMMY L PELLETIER'    from dual union all
       select 'STACIE M KINER'       from dual union all
       select 'MICHAEL C THOMAS'     from dual union all
       select 'CHESTER R DAVIS'      from dual union all
       select 'MICHAEL D HUTCHINSON' from dual union all
       select 'Paul  Mikkelsen'      from dual
     )
select initcap(substr(str, 1, instr(str, ' ') - 1)) as first_name,
       upper(trim(substr(str, instr(str, ' '), 
               instr(str, ' ', -1) - instr(str, ' ')))) as mid_in,
       initcap(substr(str, instr(str, ' ', -1) + 1)) as last_name
from   input_strings;

FIRST_NAME                     MID_IN LAST_NAME
------------------------------ ------ ------------------------------
William                               Sears
Peter                          E      Labbe
Edith                                 Roberts
Sherry                         L      Cleaves
Sharon                                Matthes
Tammy                          L      Pelletier
Stacie                         M      Kiner
Michael                        C      Thomas
Chester                        R      Davis
Michael                        D      Hutchinson
Paul                                  Mikkelsen

11 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't forget regular expressions!  Assuming your (really too simple for names) given specs for names which assume a space for a delimiter, and the fact you are not dealing with the usual name issues, this is really just parsing a delimited string which can be done with a regex that can handle NULL list elements (the middle initial):

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
   select 'William  Sears'       from dual union all
   select 'PETER E LABBE'        from dual union all
   select 'Edith  Roberts'       from dual union all
   select 'SHERRY L CLEAVES'     from dual union all
   select 'Sharon  Matthes'      from dual union all
   select 'TAMMY L PELLETIER'    from dual union all
   select 'STACIE M KINER'       from dual union all
   select 'MICHAEL C THOMAS'     from dual union all
   select 'CHESTER R DAVIS'      from dual union all
   select 'MICHAEL D HUTCHINSON' from dual union all
   select 'Paul  Mikkelsen'      from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(name, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) first_name,
          regexp_substr(name, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) mid_init,
          regexp_substr(name, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) last_name
   from tbl;

FIRST_NAME           MID_INIT             LAST_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
William                                   Sears
PETER                E                    LABBE
Edith                                     Roberts
SHERRY               L                    CLEAVES
Sharon                                    Matthes
TAMMY                L                    PELLETIER
STACIE               M                    KINER
MICHAEL              C                    THOMAS
CHESTER              R                    DAVIS
MICHAEL              D                    HUTCHINSON
Paul                                      Mikkelsen

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Yes, it's been said a million times but I'll save you the trouble: substr()/instr() is faster but I find the nested substr()/instr() syntax more ghastly than the ghastly regex syntax.  I'm probably in the minority.  Flame away anyway, you know you can't help yourself!  :-)

Comment: Gary -  I am in the majority in preferring instr/substr (for performance), as illustrated by the solution I proposed, but I agree with you that the regexp solutions are easier to write, read/understand and maintain in most cases. If maintenance is a concern (as it very often is), I might write a regexp solution even if it's slower just for that reason.

Comment: However, the solution you proposed will fail if you have first_name, then just one space instead of two, and then last_name. It will only work if first_name and last_name are separated by two spaces when there is no middle initial.

Comment: @mathguy I usually prefer ease of maintenance over convoluted code as well (ends up being cheaper in the long run) but will concede in a case like this if it will be touching millions of rows I would take the performance route. As for the other comment, I addressed that at the start by mentioning this solution is based on the spec (and the example names) that will still have the spaces even if no initial is present. I suspect this is an exercise anyway as this is not handling real-life name forms but you guys have discussed that already.

Comment: @mathguy 

Hello everyone,
 I see a little discussion going on this question. I would like to say few words.
1) THIS IS NOT FOR ANY REPORTING OR SPECIAL PURPOSE.
2) Basically, if this was needed I would have done via Function.
3) Now you guys might think why I even bothered to ask the question, I was just curious about the different ways of doing it via SQL and I’m not as good as people here in SQL.
4) I just wanted to improve my SQL knowledge. 
5) Finally, Thank you everyone for your replies.

Comment: @Developer - Hi, that makes perfect sense, thanks for clarifying. Learning for your own purposes is absolutely a legitimate goal and a valid use of SO (it would help if posters would state this goal explicitly, when that's the case). Wondering only about the "function" thing; if this was in fact a real-life requirement, it would probably be done best in plain SQL and not in a function. Regardless - good luck!

Comment: @mathguy 
Plain SQL, How? The same way you posted? Our names are usually in this format "Russo,Edward A" (LN,FN  MN) and we write a function and in the function we use Find(",", &name) following with if conditions and loops. I also know one of the SQL way via REGEX as follows:
regexp_substr(input_str, '^([^,]+),'        , 1, 1, null, 1) as   last_name,
       regexp_substr(input_str, ',\s*([^\s]+)'     , 1, 1, null, 1) as  first_name,
       regexp_substr(input_str, ',\s*[^\s]+\s+(.*)', 1, 1, null, 1) as middle_name
and thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: No, what I meant is whatever complicated expressions you can build with regexp functions (or with non-regexp functions) can also be coded directly in SQL, with the same functions. Of course the solution would be much more complicated - hyphenated names, apostrophes, Spanish names that may be 12 words long... I know; what I meant was, you don't need to write PL/SQL code for that.